# Ethernet plug light no longer shuts off, even when laptop completely shut down

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, hibernate

The ethernet light used to shut off and stay off when I close the lid (hibernate) or even sleep. Now as of a few weeks ago it turns off briefly then comes back on and stays on even if I shut down. I tried disabling the wake on magic and pattern match in the network controller, the WOL is disabled in settings. There is no option in the bios for it that I can find. This is very annoying because I keep the laptop beside my bed and it light's up the whole room. I had this laptop for years, all through windows 7 and windows 10 until a few weeks ago the light turned off when I shut the lid or shut it down. What else can I try?

Comment: When you shut down the computer, (a) ensure it is off and that your shut down command did not hibernate the machine; and (b) remove the Ethernet cable when you shut it down.

Comment: I am not on windows now, but maybe power saving settings on the NIC in device manager? At least for the close lid part. And there must have been a change in your environment - either HW or SW. Was there an OS or driver update? Did you change the router?